# What is the "international" english culture in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, cultureinfo

I have a localized application and I want to set English as the default language, but using "international" formats:

- date format (dd/MM/yy - 31/12/2014)
- comma "," as decimal separator (0,5 = 1/2)
- dot "." as thousands separator (1.000.000 = one million)

I want to set this as a global app setting, I can't work with annotations for this (as seen in other posts), and the solution should not be view-specific.

In other words, I am looking for an "en-INTERNATIONAL" CultureInfo.

Comment: i think it is called a neutral culture as opposed to a specific culture that also specifies the region. you can create one like this: var culture=new CultureInfo("en");

Comment: Would that solve the issue of the comma as a decimal and dot as a thousands separator?  I'm not aware of any English speaking countries that use that format.

Comment: It's not intended for english-speaking countries only. In most countries the dates as dd/MM/yy and the comma is the decimal separator, and English is a language that most people understand.

Comment: @flo_badea changing to "en" still has the date and number formats as en-US. WPF defaults to en-US for some UI things. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: this is because the neutral culture is very close to the specific US culture.

Comment: @flo_badea the neutral culture is not at all close to the US culture. Both dates and number formats are different. Of course, if it's a company in the US defining "neutral" it may look similar, but all around the world people do things differently.

Comment: i know they are different according to the region where english is spoken (us, gb, etc). what i was trying to say is that if you are not looking for a specific english culture (ex: en-US or en-GB) you should use the neutral one (ex: en). this more closely matches that 'en-international' thing you were mentioning. 'en' is english but it's not specific to any region. and of course it has settings. one thing you could try is to create your own culture based on the 'en' neutral culture and use that. you can use the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class for this.

Comment: @flo_badea thank you for your input. I want English language because it's widely understood but I'm not thinking about English-speaking countries, I'm thinking of countries that speak arabic, chinese, hindi, etc. That's why I want English language but not English "culture". Using just "en" defaults to american formats, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from answer by blackn1ght for WPF (as originally requested)

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");

    var numberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
    numberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator = ",";
    numberFormat.PercentGroupSeparator = ".";
    numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
    numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
    numberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
    numberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

    culture.NumberFormat = numberFormat;

    Dispatcher.Thread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Dispatcher.Thread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
}
```

Date format dd/MM/yyyy is used in the UK, so en-GB should satisfy that requirement.

Comment: So your question is wrong? You don't want the international format, you want a specific format?

Comment: @Herdo what do you understand as international format exactly? I want English language with dd/MM/yy date format, and dot as thousands separator and comma as decimal separator.

Comment: The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is the international standard for date and time formats. You cannot use standard formats for the currency, due to this is dependent on the currency. There are [official guidelines](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-370303.htm) e.g. for the Euro. You can take a look at [this post](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/international-currency-formatting-guidelines-currency-codes) for more information. When you localize an application, you should **not** use one format for everything. You should adjust your application to the rules.

Comment: Thank you @Herdo for your links. I know there's not ONE standard for every country, that's why I localized my app. The thing is, I wanted the most neutral thing available to avoid localizing to every single country in the world. I need to make compromises somewhere.

Comment: There's no need to localize it for every single country. Microsoft did this already for you. If you use the culture provided by the OS, you will be fine. If you de-/serialize data, it will be stored in a .NET format anyway. And having the data displayed in your loca style is much more pleasing, as you might not understand the other format correct.

Comment: @Herdo but what should I do with the language? I have my localized strings, and to use them the user needs to select a language for the app. Thing is, there is not just a "language" to select, he must select a full culture, which comes with dates and number formatting. Or is there a way to select a culture for the app, but keep using OS culture for dates and numbers?

Comment: It depends on how you localized your application. Normally, the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` should not effect the string localization. If you use resource files, you just need to set the language of the resource class.

Comment: @Herdo I use resource files, but setting the culture does affect the resource that the app uses. How can I change the resource used, if not by changing the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture? As far as I know, that's the standard way when working with resources. Thanks

Comment: The code generation of the resource files should generate a `Culture` property for the resource class. Just set this property and the other properties will return the value in that specific culture, if it exists, or its default.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% about this so someone please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but this may work:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

        var numberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
        numberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator = ",";
        numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
        numberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
        numberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat = numberFormat;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @blackn1ght, but what about the dates?

Comment: We use dd/MM/yyyy in the UK so en-GB should satisfy that requirement.